# Resources for understanding Gaussian processes

Tags: references, gaussian-process

I want to learn about Gaussian processes (I have a special interest in Gaussian processes for classification).

Do you know some resources / references from which I can learn (aside of the ["Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning" book](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/))?

I have a basic knowledge of calculus and probability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chapter 6.4 of Bishop's [PRML](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387310738) book explains Gaussian Processes for regression and classification. In addition, Murphy's [ML book](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/MLbook/) discusses GP latent variable models and connections with other methods. The web-site (http://www.gaussianprocess.org/) accompanying the GP book has additional implementation resources.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend the Distill.pub article on [visual exploration of Gaussian processes](https://distill.pub/2019/visual-exploration-gaussian-processes/) that provides a lot of intuitive understanding. You can also watch the video recordings of past [Gaussian process summer schools](http://gpss.cc/).

Answer (score 0):

I read the scikit-learn [documentation on Gaussian processes](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/gaussian_process/plot_gp_regression.html) in order to learn the basics.